# why date operations are strange in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am new to Java Script and I am developing a web page and the web page would have interactive contents depending on the date selected via datepicker.

I am using `var date = new Date()`, and the date creation is working fine when i use my machine in India. But when when i use the same new Date() in American time zone VMs via my Indian machine, the date returned is one day previous than entered in the date picker.

So, i suppose locales and timezones are coming into picture.

Is there any way that i could get the same date as entered in the date picker without the consideration of locales and timezones?

Comment: are you using `<input type=date>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` object works in the local timezone of the JavaScript engine (the browser, if you're using a browser).

If you're sending that information to a server in a different timezone, the best thing to do is generally to send it as an ISO string:

```
var dateString = dt.toISOString();
```

...which will give you something like this `"2015-03-20T09:07:07.193Z"`.

Then ensure that your server interprets the date correctly as a UTC date (it will always have that `Z` timezone indicator on the end, indicating UTC).

Alternately, you can use `getTime` to get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight GMT (UTC) (aka "The Epoch"):

```
var epochMilliseconds = dt.getTime();
```

...and use that server-side with whatever `Date` type the server supports; they all have a means of converting either milliseconds-since-the-Epoch or seconds-since-the-Epoch into a date/time. (If you're worried about dates *before* 1970, don't be; we just use negative numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's Date class doesn't represent a date, it represents a timestamp (same in Java). To make it a date

```
new Date()
```

should work fine, but if you are using date format at yyyy-mm-dd, then change it to yyyy/mm/dd and it should work fine.